# MS Azure Text Analytics API:4 in 1 API or 4 APIs?

Tags: azure, api, text, analytics

It seems like [Azure Text Analytics API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/) can provide sentiment analysis, key phrase extraction, language detection and entities identification in one JSON response.

But I didn't find any details about performing all 4 of those tasks in 1 API request. Do I have to use 4 different API endpoints to perform those 4 tasks individually?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c7, it appears that these are in fact 4 separate POST endpoints. The responses don't seem to share any commonality. You'll probably have to hit them and pay for them separately.

You could look at some other cloud providers (Amazon, Google) and see if the services they offer fit your use case any better.

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct, each service is provided by a separate API endpoint.